# Django 'PictureForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: django

I'm trying to add a new feature to my existing app that let users create a profile and upload a pictures of their pets.

When a user login , he gets redirected into the profile which display his name and also he can add a picture of himself into the model which will get displayed on the profile page.

[image]

At the moment , I can retrieve the name into the template but I can't seem to display the user's name and upload picture at the same time.

Whenever I click Add picture , It doesn't let the user upload a picture instead I get this error

```
'PictureForm' object has no attribute 'save'
 pet = form.save(commit =False) ...
```

I could design the  page to let the user upload a picture but not display the name at the same time.

I think the problem lays in my profile.html and Profile function at views.py

**Parts of my views.py**

```
@login_required     
def Profile(request):
    Person = request.user.get_profile()
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PictureForm(request.POST ,request.FILE or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            pet = form.save(commit =False)
            pet.save()
    context = (
        {'Person': Person} , 
        {'form':PictureForm()}
        )
    return render_to_response('profile.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Parts of my forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from pet.models import *

class PictureForm(forms.Form):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('image')
```

**My profile.html**

```
 {% if Person %}
 <ul>
        <li>Name : {{Person.name}} </li>
 </ul>
 {% endif %}        

 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" "action" >
 {% csrf_token %}
    <ul>
        {{ form.as_ul }}
    </ul>
    <input type = "submit" value= "Add Picture" />
 </form>
```

**My models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Pet(models.Model):
    Person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

Comment: PictureForm(request.POST ,`request.FILES` or None)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erase your form.save(commit=False). You will only do that if you override your save method

```
@login_required     
def Profile(request):
    Person = request.user.get_profile()
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PictureForm(request.POST ,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = (
        {'Person': Person} , 
        {'form':PictureForm()}
        )
    return render_to_response('profile.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

UPDATE:

```
    [.....]
    board = Board.objects.get(board=picture.board)//remove this
    the_id = board.id //remove this

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:Boat', kwargs={'animal_id': picture.board.id })) // change the_id into picture.board.id
```

Comment: If your not busy , could you help me out please. . I don't understand why it's happen. The question is at the bottom of the page :]

Comment: It's at the bottom of the question . It say "Cathy Here"

Comment: Before when you upload a picture , it will redirect to the board that the picture is intend to.

Comment: `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:BoardCreator')`

Comment: Okay when you add a picture , their a dropbox that list all the boards . We worked in reverse to get the board id and filter the board id with picture . then we got the pictures for the board.

Comment: I think you got to try out my app then you can understand this funny error

Comment: Create 2 boards and add picture to both of them

Comment: Okay if you create some boards , then you try to add pictures to a particular board . It suppose to redirect you to the board that you added the picture too

Comment: ah ok I'm back to my first upload image

Comment: haha . It was working before but I can't figure out what wrong

Comment: the last two lines before return. Your pointing to the first board id

Comment: Can I ask why is it grabbing the first board ?

Comment: Thank you cathy for helping me :]

Comment: you remove the codes. Ok you equal picture.board to board. Which the Board model has no board field

Answer (score 3):

`PictureForm` needs to inherit from `forms.ModelForm`, not `forms.Form`.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman . What does this error mean Unknown field(s) (i, a, m, e, g) specified for Person when I click on  add picture

Comment: It means that this: `fields = ('image')` should be this: `fields = ('image',)`

Comment: what can we do IF we use 'form.Form' cause it is a simple upload without binding to a model. then which PictureBlaBla variable is suiting that?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo.  It should be `request.FILES`.

Comment: Thank for the help but I still won't allow me to add pictures

Answer (score 0):

no buddy. your problem is in your model.py:

just add this function to your model

```
def save(self,*args, **kw):
super(PictureForm,self).save(*args, **kw)
```